# Cant connect to PC via SSH

Tags: wireless, lan, ssh

I use Windows 7 on my desktop.
I tried to connect my Android to my PC via Wi-Fi connection.
SSH port 22 is open on my desktop.
I use Connectbot to connect to my pc .

The result of ipconfig:

```
C:\Windows\system32>­ipconfigWindows IP ConfigurationEthernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : domain.name
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::286c:2b76:ae18­:18f5%14
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::6e72:20ff:fe7d­:1063%14192.168.0.1
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnectedConnection-specific 
DNS Suffix . :Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:Connection-specific 
DNS Suffix . :Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::79f7:d7d6:8a1f­:4c13%11
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.25
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.129
C:\Windows\system32>
```

From connectbot via ssh:

```
Connecting to 192.168.0.2:
The authenticity of host 'lished.
Host EC key fingerprint is:6c:de:6c:f6:c0:78:2a
Key exchange was not finis
The server hostkey was not allback

Connection Lost
```

Ping result from android:

```
app_30@android:/ $ ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.13 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=1.46 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=1.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=1.45 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=1.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=1.49 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=1.44 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=1.43 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=9 ttl=128 time=1.40 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=10 ttl=128 time=1.37 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Windows machine's host key may have changed since the last time you tried to connect using ConnectBot. If you remove and then re-add the windows machine to the ConnectBot hosts list you might be able to connect.

Comment: I tried but of no use

Comment: Connection works with USB.

Comment: It looks like there's some text missing from the error message you posted in the question, specifically this bit:  `rom connectbot via ssh:

Connecting to 192.168.0.2: The authenticity of host ' lished. Host EC key fingerprint is :6c:de:6c:f6:c0:78:2a Key exchange was not finis The server hostkey was not allback

Connection Lost`

Comment: No, that was the complete error message

Comment: Are you able to try authenticating via public key instead of password?

Comment: Im new to SSH. would you mind telling me how to do so?

Comment: Google will be a far better resource than me here, I haven't used a windows-based ssh server before.  The basic process is to generate a keypair on your android (Connectbot>>manage pubkeys>>generate) then paste the public key you generated into the authorized keys file on the server.  This will allow any device that has the private key that matches the public key to connect without a password (the private key effectively becomes the password).